# installing CakePHP 2 in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, cakephp-2.0, ubuntu-11.04

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 with Apache/MySQL/PHP5 installed. I completely followed the installation process form this link:

```
[http://developify.wordpress.com/2011/08/12/install-cakephp-on-ubuntu/][1]
```

And I ended up in a CakePHP default page with no colors/styles, though this error was wrapped in red background:

```
URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server. 1) Help me configure it 2) I don't / can't use URL rewriting
```

mod_rewrite is already enabled, I don't know what is the problem with my installation.

And also, if I replaced the default layout by making my own default.ctp, I am bombarded with these lines of error:

```
Warning (2): include(/var/www/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp): failed to open stream: Permission denied [CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 595]

Warning (2): include() [http://php.net/function.include]: Failed opening '/var/www/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') [CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 595]
```

BTW, in Windows it works perfectly, maybe MS doesn't care with file permissions.

Please help me, I am new with CakePHP. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your apache/php user has permission to read all of cake's files. Something like `chmod -R 755 ./*`